# Ethers.js JsonRpcProvider Geth node in a Docker environment

Tags: docker, docker-compose, blockchain, ethereum, geth

I am trying to connect Ethers.js to a local Ehereum node (Geth) running in a Docker container. On the client side, I'm creating the provider this way: `new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider('http://geth:8545')`. `geth` is the node container hostname and both containers are on the same network: I can ping the Geth node from within the client container. When I start requesting the node from the client, I get a `"noNetwork"` error.

When I run the client without Docker, requesting the node container through `http://localhost:8545`, it is working properly.

What's wrong?

- Docker-compose file for the Geth node:

```yaml
version: "3.5"

services:
  geth:
    container_name: geth
    image: ethereum/client-go:latest
    volumes:
      - /etc/geth:/root/.ethereum:rw
    ports:
      - "8545:8545"
      - "30303:30303"
    networks:
      - ethereum
    entrypoint: "geth --nousb --http --http.corsdomain '*' --http.addr 0.0.0.0 --http.api personal,eth,net,web3 --syncmode light"

networks:
  ethereum:
    name: ethereum-net
```

- Docker-compose file for the client:

```yaml
version: "3.5"

services:
  eth-server:
    container_name: eth_server_dev
    build: packages/eth-server/.
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - NODE_PORT=3002
    volumes:
      - ./packages/eth-server/log:/app/log:rw
    ports:
      - "3002:3000"
    networks:
      - ethereum

networks:
  ethereum:
    external:
      name: ethereum-net
```

- Error:

```
/app/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:179
         var error = new Error(message);
                     ^

 Error: could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.0.17)
     at Logger.makeError (/app/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:179:21)
     at Logger.throwError (/app/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:188:20)
     at JsonRpcProvider.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:407:54)
     at step (/app/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:46:23)
     at Object.throw (/app/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:27:53)
     at rejected (/app/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:19:65)
     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5) {
   reason: 'could not detect network',
   code: 'NETWORK_ERROR',
   event: 'noNetwork'
 }
```

Comment: give me eth-server's entry server code, specifically the code corresponding to the input parameter part connecting to geth-client